# How to send email using aws with different regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

We need to send invitation email from our website hosted on an EC2 instance. Our regular email service is hosted by Google.

The problem is that we are based in US East Ohio region where SES is not available. So can we change our region just for using SES? Will it impact our EC2 instance? Can't find any documentation regarding this.

and when i try to send email the error come is

```
{ UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-2' region.
at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi's/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:456:46)
at Request.callListeners (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi's/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi's/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi's/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at ClientRequest.error (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi's/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:295:22)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi's/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:89:19)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:160:13)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:389:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:160:13)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

message: 'Inaccessible host: `email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\'. This service may not be available in the`us-east-2\' region.',
  code: 'UnknownEndpoint',
  region: 'us-east-2',
  hostname: 'email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  originalError: 
   { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:55:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:26)
     message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443',
     code: 'NetworkingError',
     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
     host: 'email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
     port: 443,
     region: 'us-east-2',
     retryable: true,
     time: 2018-02-26T10:08:25.003Z },
  time: 2018-02-26T10:08:25.003Z } 'UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\'. This service may not be available in the`us-east-2\' region.\n    at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi\'s/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:456:46)\n    at Request.callListeners (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi\'s/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)\n    at Request.emit (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi\'s/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)\n    at Request.emit (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi\'s/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)\n    at ClientRequest.error (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi\'s/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:295:22)\n    at ClientRequest. (/home/pc-09/PlayScoreApi\'s/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:89:19)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:160:13)\n    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:389:9)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:160:13)\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)'

Answer (score 1):

It's no problem using SES endpoint from another region, it will work just fine - there may be some additional costs related to out-of-region bandwidth charges as you ec2 instance will be sending traffic to another region, but unless you are sending a tremendous amount of email, I can't image it will amount to much at all.

Comment: How to use SES endpoint from another region ? any link or tutorial link will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke SES endpoint in other regions without issues. However, SES is supported in a few regions only. They are: Virginia, Oregon and Ireland. The details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html). Ohio is currently not yet supported.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for answering, I have solved this issue by sending mail using Simple SMTP like nodemailer in nodejs Without AWS Config.  So, when i load code on AWS server, then it sending mails.